# Backgroundworker does not perform cancel operation

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, .net-framework-version

I've created a backgroundworker to load data from a file. So far it works as intented but when I try to add a way to cancel the operation it doesnt work however I try. For testing I've broken the logic down to miminum but the result stays unchanged.
I also confirmed, that the backgroundworker and the caller are not operating on the same thread.

Initialization of the Worker (inside of the class FileLoader):

```
private BackgroundWorker Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
private ManualResetEvent WorkerDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public FileLoader()
{
   Worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
   Worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
   Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
}

public void LoadAsync() => Worker.RunWorkerAsync();

public void CancelLoad()
{
   if (!Worker.IsBusy) return;
   WorkerDone.Reset();
   Worker.CancelAsync();
   WorkerDone.WaitOne();
}
```

Worker Functions:

```
private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    object data = new object();

    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    if (worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }            
    e.Result = data;
}

private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cancel requested");
        WorkerDone.Set();
    }
    else LoadCompleted?.Invoke(this, e.Result);
}
```

If no cancel is requested the worker operates as expected and `Worker_RunWorkerCompleted` is called. But when a cancel is requested `Worker_DoWork` is terminated and `e.Cancel` is set to true but `Worker_RunWorkerCompleted` is never called in any way and the cancel operation freezes.

According to the documentation of Backgroundworker the `RunWorkerCompleted` event should always fire when the assigned function ends regardless of an cancel or not.

Comment: It is called *deadlock*.  The RunWorkerCompleted event handler cannot run, the UI thread is hung on the WaitOne() call.  Like any thread it can only do one thing at a time.  Never hang the UI thread.  You forgot to tell us why you need this code to work so concrete advice is hard to come by.

Comment: As I said above, the backgroundworker is running on a separate thread from the UI, I especially checked that in the debugger. And the reason why this code should work is that based on the Microsoft documentation the Completed-Event should always fire when the Function ends.

Comment: _"the Completed-Event should always fire when the Function ends"_ -- it does "fire", in that the `BackgroundWorker` tries to raise it. But your code can't ever know about because **one of the other promises the documentation tells you** is that the event will be raised on the UI thread (i.e. the thread owning the `BackgroundWorker` object), and that thread can't do anything **because you've blocked it** waiting on the `WorkerDone.WaitOne();` statement. Just like you've already been told. It is highly unlikely that you need `WorkerDone` at all here. Please explain why you think otherwise.

Comment: See marked duplicate. While it's blocking on a call to `Thread.Join()` instead of `WaitOne()`, and it uses an explicit flag variable to signal the background worker to stop rather than the built-in cancellation mechanism, it is essentially identical to your scenario.